# Magento 2 How can i add BCC to order email with observer programatically?

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, customer, email

I have created module and wrote one an observer on "**order_place_after**", here i want to send the same order email copy to my custom email address.

How can i send the same order email to my custom email address or add that email address as BCC to send order email copy?

Thanks

Comment: Why you want it through observer? You can override the order email or use plugin.

Comment: i have module which has functionality to configure email addresses to each customers from admin side. so when that customer order something then the configured email address also will get same notification.

Answer (score 6):

You can managed to work it by follwoing code:

**Step 1:** Create a module with name **Vendor_Module** and do the following changes.

**Step 2:** create **di.xml** under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" />
</config>
```

**Step 3:** Create **SenderBuilder.php** under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Order/Email/SenderBuilder.php

with content:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Email;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilderByStore;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;

class SenderBuilder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder
{
    protected $templateContainer;
    protected $identityContainer;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    private $transportBuilderByStore;

    public function __construct(
        Template $templateContainer,
        IdentityInterface $identityContainer,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        TransportBuilderByStore $transportBuilderByStore = null
    ) {
        $this->templateContainer = $templateContainer;
        $this->identityContainer = $identityContainer;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->transportBuilderByStore = $transportBuilderByStore ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            TransportBuilderByStore::class
        );
        parent::__construct($templateContainer, $identityContainer, $transportBuilder, $this->transportBuilderByStore);
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $custom_email = 'YOUR_DYNAMIC_EMAIL_ADDRESS';

        $this->configureEmailTemplate();

        $this->transportBuilder->addTo(
            $this->identityContainer->getCustomerEmail(),
            $this->identityContainer->getCustomerName()
        );

        $copyTo = $this->identityContainer->getEmailCopyTo();

        if (!empty($copyTo) && $this->identityContainer->getCopyMethod() == 'bcc') {
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $this->transportBuilder->addBcc($email);
            }
        }

        if($custom_email){
            $this->transportBuilder->addBcc($custom_email); // Added for add BCC for custom dynamic email address
        }

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
    }
}
```

And now run required commands like setup:upgrade, di compile etc. You can modify the codes according to your requirement.

***Note: Above codes are not Tested but it should work.***

Comment: how should i use with my observer, as i have already created one observer.

Comment: @UtsavGupta add your code in question will surely help you out

Comment: anyone know how I can achieve this but with magento 1.9

Comment: Hello, can I load order here ? I want to add bcc but it is base on some order value. May I get Order in this same function ?

Comment: @Sukumar Gorai: what do you think plugin can work on this class instead preference.